# Simplifying $\frac{4}{2x-7}-\frac{3}{(2x-7)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

A homework question asks me to "perform the addition or subtraction and simplify"

$$
\begin{gather}
\frac{4}{2x-7}-\frac{3}{(2x-7)^2}=4(2x-7)-3=8x-28-3=8x-31 \\
8x=31 \\
x=\frac{31}{8}
\end{gather}
$$

Is my work and answer correct?

Answer (score 5):

If you cited the text of the exercise correctly, then you don't have to find the zero places of the given expression, only simplify it.

Writing $=$ between terms which are not equal, looks very *ugly* in math (is a sin).

Instead, it would be only:
$$\frac 4{2x-7}-\frac 3{(2x-7)^2} = \frac{8x-31}{(2x-7)^2}\,.$$

Comment: aren't the terms in my question equal? Why can't I use =? Am I suppose to start a new line?

Comment: @Ben The first $=$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, perfect :), first you made the denominator equal and then it's straightforward.

But is this solving for $x$ or simplifying?

Comment: the question says "perform the addition or subtraction and simplify". Guess I am not suppose to find the value of x?

Comment: I guess not ;), you can have a look at Berci's post for the simplifying!